# ASP.Net file upload/browser component

Tags: asp.net, iis, file-upload

I might end up having to build this, but it would be nice if there is a solution already...

I need to add functionality to a client's web page to allow them to upload files, and then to view and download them.  We also need some form of authentication mechanism to restrict who has access to which files.  I have used [Neat Upload](http://www.brettle.com/neatupload) in the past and have found that it works pretty well, but it only handles upload.  If there is a control that does *everything*, that would be pretty nice.  Has anyone seen or used anything like that?  I am working in ASP.Net.  Our server is IIS 6, but I cannot confirm which version of IIS the client is using.

Comment: Not sure if I fully understand your requirement.  Once uploaded, the document needs to be rendered on the page for them, with something like a "download" link next to it?

Comment: I assume he means the dev webserver is IIS6, but doesn't know what webserver his client's will host this upon.

Comment: @Gurdas Not rendered, I need to present a list of all the files that have been uploaded

Comment: Another question that should be asked is what type of authentication does your site already use? Does it use membership provider or did you roll your own?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have that information either.  I haven't actually seen the site yet, so I have no technical details.  I'm just looking to see what is out there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some more searching, and found this.  I think it will fit our needs perfectly

edit:  The link didn't come through.  The solution is FileVista, at http://www.gleamtech.com/products/filevista/web-file-manager

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Neat Upload or some other upload component and integrating ASP.NET membership services to manage permissions.

Comment: That would be my first inclination, but I was asked to look for a ready-made solution.  They are already using Sharepoint for this purpose but are not happy with it.  I am not entirely clear why